# html 5 v/s XHTML

Tags: html

Which is better to learn HTML 5 or XHTML?

Answer (score 6):

HTML 5 supports two syntaxes. One of those syntaxes is XHTML.

Don't limit what you learn: if you plan to write HTML in the future, learn about HTML 5 and understand *both* syntaxes it uses.

If you're writing HTML today, still learn about HTML 5, but stick to the tags which currently work (i.e. those compatible with HTML 4 or XHTML 2 as appropriate to the syntax you use.)

Comment: +1 - Agree that HTML 5 is the way. As a side note, HTML 5 is designed to be VERY backwards compatible with HTML 4. Even many of the new bits degrade nicely, for example HTML 5 Form inputs like date, email, url etc all just display as text inputs in older browsers. There really is no reason to delay using HTML 5.

Answer (score 2):

XHTML specs are not backwards compatible which necessarily puts a damper on wide-spread adaption.  Your investment in todays version of XHTML gives you nothing over todays HTML when moving to tommorrows version of XHTML.  They are essentially the same source documents that can be trivially converted from HTML to XHTML.

All major browser vendors do not support XHTML which makes widespread adaption today impossible.

In my view Hand-coding documents in XML is not an ideal or bandwidth effecient endeavour.   With HTML I don't need to worry about case sensitivity, spacing, having closing tags or /> syntax for items that don't need them.  XML is too pedantic a syntax for widespread human consumption in my view.

I see too many people adding XHTML doctypes and actually thinking browsers are rendering XHTML when in fact they are ignoring the tags alltogether.  I'm sure people have their reasons but I fear a non-trivial majority choose XHTML simply because its the latest buzzword.

The only actual benefit I know of currently to XHTML is that the format of the document can be validated using a validating XML parser.  There have been HTML "lint" tools avaliable since Mosaic and Cello dominated the browser space.

Spec interpretations and rendering bugs have always dominated compatibility issues.. Expecting XHTML to make all your problems go away is not realistic in my view. I need not go any further than CSS :-(

Comment: Not really true about the browser support. All the major players (yes even IE) support it as long as you feed IE the text/html content type. XHTML also allows other XML data to be incorporated into the document using namespaces, which is important so some applications like inline SVG.

Comment: XHTML is not supported by IE (including IE8).  You must also use application/xhtml+xml or browsers will treat the XML as HTML and shall not be subject to XML validation rules.

Comment: Contrary viewpoint: The primary consumers of HTML are web browsers, not programmers, as there are more of the former than the latter.  It is much more important to make a language easily understood by a program (browsers and design tools) than easily written by a person.  XHTML helps make it easier to create web pages that are more likely to be consistently rendered by web browsers.

Comment: The XHTML specification says that if an error is found in the XHTML document, it should cease to be rendered. That alone makes the HTML 5 (which can be written in XML style) specification more valuable to web USERS, who are the most important people. The hierarchy according to W3C is USERS > DEVELOPERS > BROWSER VENDORS > W3C SPEC - that's important to remember - USERS come first!

Comment: @Sohnee: That's only a problem if you don't validate. If you give the end-user an invalid Python program, for example, it *crashes*; it's your responsibility to test your program, not the interpreter's to guess what you meant. Why should invalid XHTML be any different?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - Web pages are not just written by developers. Anyone should be able to write a web page, that's the key to the openness of the web. Also, if you write a content management system using a "contentEditable" field, the user's choice of browser may mean invalid XHTML gets written into the content editable field - thus their page no longer renders. (X)HTML is not a program, it is a mark-up for sharing information peer-to-peer without prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

You mean "[(x)HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/)" aka "[Web Applications 1.0](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/)" or "[XHTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/)"? Since it will take a couple more years until one or both of these techniques will be fully usable, I would suggest starting with pure and simple XHtml1.0. You will find quite some good tutorials and you can use your xhtml with any actual browser. To later change or update your knowledge to the [final draft and the small nuances](http://xhtml.com/en/future/x-html-5-versus-xhtml-2/) will be very easy once you already know one of the old versions.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on HTML5. While there are features in HTML5 that are not widely supported, they are optional features; if you don't use them, your pages will still work properly, and you won't be any more hampered than if you used xhtml instead. Plus, browser support for those features is growing quickly, and even IE can be made to support much of the feature set through javascript shims.

Comment: +1 indeed - and there are non-JavaScript shims available too - although you need to balance mark-up vs JavaScript support.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML allows SVG graphics and other XML content to be embedded inline (this is a good thing for decorative flair). HTML5 is still undecided in this regard. Other than than it's probably 50/50. HTML allows you to be more sloppy with your code which might be a good thing while you're learning.

Comment: I'm not convinced if the tolerant attitude of HTML is a good thing for novices. I remember that the unforgiving nature of C compilers made me learn a lot back then even though that meant a steep learning curve.

Comment: HTML is more forgiving (by design - the specification tells browser vendors how to handle some mark-up errors) - but you can be as strict as you like. The browser shouldn't enforce the strictness - your development environment should. The idea behind the "forgiving browsers" is that it lets ANYONE publish a web page - not just clever developers!

Comment: HTML 5 now allows MathML and (I think) SVG.

Answer (score -1):

Both. I'd focus on XHTML as current browser support for HTML5 is pretty low.

Comment: The *new* features in HTML 5 aren't widely supported, but it incorporates a lot of commonly used tags and attributes that are invalid in XHTML (e.g., canvas and the target attribute).

Comment: Did you know that IE has never supported XHTML? I'd say browser support for HTML(5) is still higher.